# Basic auth with OpenLayers 3

Tags: openlayers-3

I have OpenLayers embedded in a desktop application and I'm trying to request a WMS map layer from a server that requires authentication.

Because of the environment I can't have the popup that a browser would typically display to require authentication and that wouldn't be acceptable to a customer anyway.

For now I want to use the format of https://{username}:{password}@domain.com/wms?

If I pass that to OpenLayers as the url of a ol.source.TileWMS the requests have the username and password removed and I always see 401 errors returned and looking at the url the username and password has been stripped off.

Comment: can you use jquery to make the request? http://stackoverflow.com/a/5507289/2730610

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try creating your layer with a [tileUrlFunction](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/113384/implementing-openlayers3-basemap-from-tiles-created-using-gdal2tiles).

```
var tileUrlFunction = function(tileCoord, pixelRatio, projection) {
  if (!tileCoord) { return ""; }

  var x = tileCoord[1];
  var y = tileCoord[2];
  var z = tileCoord[0];

  return 'https://{username}:{password}@localhost/map-tiles/' + z + '/' + x + '/' + y + '.png';
}

var layers = [
  new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.XYZ({
      tileUrlFunction: tileUrlFunction
    })
  })
];
```

EDIT: The use of embedded "user:password" authentication in the URL has been deprecated by [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986), so this will no longer work with modern browsers.

Comment: I found many browser will block this request owing to authentication credentials in the URL being deprecated.

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of it.

Comment: You're welcome!  It's a pain but make's sense.  Consider using http headers instead perhaps.